# Unpivot on aggregated columns

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, unpivot

I'm trying for 3 days now to format a sql output so that i can put it in an excel sheet with PHPExcel with the less steps as possible (because i have a very huge Excel sheet to generate)

I am using SQL SERVER 2005

This is what I get Without using any pivot (Because i don't how to do it ..)

```
- [cause]                  |[nb]| [Value]

- CASSE                    | 20 |  8568,74
- DELEGATION SIGNATURE     |  2 |  1268,96
- ERREUR DE LIVRAISON      |  8 |  1654,64
- INTERNE                  | 10 |  3145,7
- PERTE                    | 94 | 26255,08
- SPOLIATION               |  2 |   420
- VOL                      | 41 |  5747,76
```

SO now what i want to get is somethng like this :

```
- [cause]                |  [Value]

- CASSE                  |   20
- CASSE                  | 8568,74
- DELEGATION SIGNATURE   |    2
- DELEGATION SIGNATURE   | 1268,96
- ...
```

Here is what I've done :

```
 SELECT 
        l1.Litige_Cause AS [cause], count(l2.Litige_Ref) AS [nb], 
      sum(lc.LitigeCProduit_Valeur) as [value]
    FROM 
       LitigeCordon l1 
     LEFT JOIN LitigeCordon l2 
       ON l1.Litige_Ref = l2.Litige_Ref
       AND YEAR(l2.Litige_DateEnvoi) = 2014 AND MONTH(l2.Litige_DateEnvoi) = 01
       INNER JOIN LitigeCProduit lc
       ON l1.Litige_Ref = lc.Litige_Ref
       AND YEAR(l2.Litige_DateEnvoi) = 2014 AND MONTH(l2.Litige_DateEnvoi) = 01         GROUP BY l1.Litige_Cause
```

Well, it must admit i'm not really good at SQL, i'm still a student, and what i learned at school are barely the basics. SO my question : is it even possible ? If yes, could you give me an advice, because i'm not searching   only for a raw answer, i would like to understand more how the pivot / Unpivot functions are working, i already tried many things but it never worked like a wanted to ...

Thanks !

---

Edit :
For those who might be interrested, I made some changes to @NoDisplayName answer, so that the result looks like this :

```
- [cause]                Type |  [Value]

- CASSE                    NB |   20
- CASSE                  Value| 8568,74
- DELEGATION SIGNATURE     NB |    2
- DELEGATION SIGNATURE   Value| 1268,96
- ...
```

I only added the column "type" and unpivoted data for "type" instead of "col"

```
  SELECT cause, type,
   data as Value
  FROM  (SELECT cause,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), nb) nb1,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), value) value1
         FROM   Yourtable) a
  UNPIVOT(data
            FOR type IN([nb1],
                       [value1]))unpiv
```

Hopes this helps too :)

Comment: simple hack: `select cause, nb from yourtable union all select cause, value from your table`

Comment: Refer to @Jayvee answer and the comments. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do this using `Cross Apply` simple way to `Unpivot` your data

```
SELECT cause,
       cs.value
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply(VALUES (value),
                          (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), nb))) cs (value)
```

Or you can also use `Unpivot`

```
SELECT cause,
       data as Value
FROM  (SELECT cause,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), nb) nb1,
                value
        FROM   Yourtable) a
        UNPIVOT(data
                FOR col IN([nb1],
                           [value]))unpiv
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b06e0/1)

Comment: I'm really thankful ! SO basically most of my fails were because i did not convert the agregated columns .... Well, thansk to you i now know !

ps: i got syntax error with the 1st solution, maybe it is not supported in SQLSERVER 2005 ?

Answer (score 0):

this should work as well:

```
SELECT l1.Litige_Cause AS [cause], count(l2.Litige_Ref) AS [nb] FROM LitigeCordon l1
UNION ALL
SELECT l1.Litige_Cause AS [cause], sum(lc.LitigeCProduit_Valeur) as [value] FROM LitigeCordon l1
ORDER BY l1.Litige_Cause
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this out, but i didn't work. After searching a bit, i found out that "UNION" isn't supported on SQLSERVER 2005 and it's only since the 2008 releases.

Comment: UNION is one of the most basic operations in an RDBMS and it's definitely supported on Sql Server 2005, this is the link to microsoft page for UNION in SQL server 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Oh, i missread something on this page(http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/en-en/library/ms180026.aspx) then, i'm sorry for that mistake ...